# Simplifying a DAG in igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs, visnetwork

I have a DAG as follows.

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(key = c("B", "A", "C", "C1", "C2", "C3", "X", "P", "Y", "M", "N", "O", 
                            "G3", "G2", "G1", "G", "R", "S", "K1", "K2", "K3", "Z", "H", "I"),
                    inter = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                              1, 1, 0, 0),
                    ret = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "T", "F", 
                            "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"))

edges <- data.frame(from = c("A", "C", "C1", "C2", "C3", "X", "M", "N", "O", "G3", "G2", 
                             "G1", "G", "R", "Z", "P", "K1", "K2", "O", "P", "B", "Y", "S", 
                             "X", "B"),
                    to = c("C", "C1", "C2", "C3", "X", "P", "Y", "M", "N", "O", "G3", 
                           "G2", "G1", "G", "R", "K1", "K2", "K3", "H", "I", "C", "P", "G", 
                           "H", "I"))

ig <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, directed = TRUE, vertices = nodes)

is.dag(ig)
[1] TRUE

igv <- visIgraph(igraph = ig, layout = "layout_with_sugiyama")

visNodes(igv, shape = "circle", value = 30)
```

[image]

I am trying to simplify the graph by merging several of the nodes.

## Vertices to be retained

1) Leaves

```
leaves <- which(degree(ig, v = V(ig), mode = "out")==0, useNames = T)
```

leaves
K3 
21

2) Explicitly specified to be retained by a node attribute ("`ret`"
)

```
nodes[nodes$ret == "T",]$key
[1] "N"
```

## Vertices to be merged

Merge a node with preceeding nodes till it matches a

1) root OR

2) a node with >1 edges directed towards it OR

3) explicitly designated one

In this example, the follwing nodes to be merged.
Simultaneously the values of the attibute needs to be added too.

{P, K1, K2, K3} = K

{C, C1, C2, C3, X} = X

{G, G1, G2, G3, O} = O

{N, M, Y} = Y

```
sum(nodes[nodes$key %in% c("P", "K1", "K2", "K3"), ]$inter)
[1] 7
sum(nodes[nodes$key %in% c("C", "C1", "C2", "C3", "X"), ]$inter)
[1] 4
sum(nodes[nodes$key %in% c("G", "G1", "G2", "G3", "O"), ]$inter)
[1] 3
sum(nodes[nodes$key %in% c("N", "M", "Y"), ]$inter)
[1] 3
```

How to find such groups of nodes and merging them along with the data and at the same time not disturbing the nodes to be retained?